# Issue with Snowflake SQL joins

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Table1:

| Application_Id | Person_ID | Repayment_date | Repayment_amount | DUE_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1234 | 2022-09-30 | 932 | 2022-06-19 |
| 001 | 1234 | 2022-10-17 | 931 | 2022-06-19 |

Table2:

| Application_ID | Person_ID | NUMBER_OF_INSTALLMENTS | STARTING_BALANCE | FIRST_INSTALLMENT_START_DATE | SECOND_INSTALLMENT_DATE | LAST_INSTALLMENT_DUE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1234 | 2 | 1863 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-10-15 | 2022-10-15 |

This is the query that i wrote:

[image: Query]

The output I am getting is this:

| Application_id | Person_ID | NUMBER_OF_INSTALLMENTS | STARTING_BALANCE | due_date | FIRST_INSTALLMENT_START_DATE | FIRST_INSTALLMENT_REPAYMENT_AMOUNT | SECOND_INSTALLMENT_DATE | SECOND_INSTALLMENT_REPAYMENT_DATE | SECOND_INSTALLMENT_REPAYMENT_AMOUNT | LAST_INSTALLMENT_DUE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1234 | 2 | 1863 | 2022-06-19 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-09-30 | 932 | 2022-10-15 | null | null |
| 001 | 1234 | 2 | 1863 | 2022-06-19 | 2022-09-30 | null | null | 2022-10-15 | 2022-10-17 | 931 |

However the expected output is:

| Application_id | Person_ID | NUMBER_OF_INSTALLMENTS | STARTING_BALANCE | due_date | FIRST_INSTALLMENT_START_DATE | FIRST_INSTALLMENT_REPAYMENT_AMOUNT | SECOND_INSTALLMENT_DATE | SECOND_INSTALLMENT_REPAYMENT_DATE | SECOND_INSTALLMENT_REPAYMENT_AMOUNT | LAST_INSTALLMENT_DUE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1234 | 2 | 1863 | 2022-06-19 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-09-30 | 932 | 2022-10-15 | 2022-10-17 | 931 |

Comment: So what is WRONG is the output you have, don't make us guess the magic difference between the two. Use your words to describe your problem.

Comment: Please don’t post images of code, as no-one can copy it if they want to try running it. Also, the tables you’ve provided don’t correspond with your code - there are missing columns

Answer (score 1):

Distinct can't be used here, because you are not looking for distinct rows. Actually it seems you are trying to merge these rows and take the columns without NULL values.

Maybe something like this can help:

```
SELECT MAX(Application_id), Person_ID, MAX(NUMBER_OF_INSTALLMENTS)
... MAX(LAST_INSTALLMENT_DUE_DATE)
from ( <your original query> )
group by Person_ID;
```